# How to scrape hidden elements without Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

I am triyng to make my small webscraping script on [this](https://samozapis-spb.ru/moskovskiy-rayon/ctomatologicheskaya-poliklinika-no12) russian website. This script have to find all available doctors.

Had some issues to get hidden class inside "Запись" tab.
After making some research I've found Selenium module and here is my code:

```
url = 'https://samozapis-spb.ru/moskovskiy-rayon/ctomatologicheskaya-poliklinika-no12'

from time import sleep
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options


opts = Options()
prefs = {"profile.managed_default_content_settings.images": 2}
opts.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
browser = Chrome(options=opts)

browser.get(url)
elems = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector('tr')
print('running chrome')

while True:
    #print(browser.session_id)
    elem = browser.find_element_by_id('show_app')
    elem.click()

    sleep(5)

    elem = browser.find_element_by_css_selector("a[class='ax list-group-item']")
    elem.click()

    doctors = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector("a[class='ax list-group-item']")[2:]

    tallons = {}

    for doc in doctors:
        temp = doc.text.split('\n')
        if len(temp) == 2:
            tallons[temp[1]]=temp[0]
    print(tallons)

    browser.refresh()
    sleep(300)
```

This script works but I don't like that it opens a browser window.

Comment: Look at [requssts-html](https://html.python-requests.org)

Comment: To disable opening a browser window, try adding `opts.headless = True`

Comment: @chitown88 this has JS support?! why has no one told me about that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can scrape the ajax request just search `data-lid` for POST body and set correct headers

```
s = requests.session()
page = s.get('https://samozapis-spb.ru/moskovskiy-rayon/ctomatologicheskaya-poliklinika-no12')

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
# get "data-lid" from the page
spec = soup.find("div", id="spec")

# do ajax request
data = {"lid": spec["data-lid"]}
headers = {"x-requested-with" : "XMLHttpRequest"}
ajax = s.post('https://samozapis-spb.ru/_api_v3/spec.php', data=data, headers=headers).json()

spec = soup.find("div", id="spec")
soup = BeautifulSoup(ajax['html'], 'html.parser')

doctors = soup.select("a[class='ax list-group-item']")[2:]

print(doctors)
```

Comment: nice, but it's really difficult to understand(
I think you are making request to spec element but what if i want to go further for example to soup.select("a[class='ax list-group-item']")[0]?

Comment: see before last line in my code you only need to change `[2:]` to `[0]` :D

Comment: you know i figured it out
'data2 = {"sid": ter["data-sid"], "shash": ter["data-shash"], "lid":358}

ajax2 = s.post('https://samozapis-spb.ru/_api_v3/docs.php', data=data2, headers=headers).json()
soup2 = BeautifulSoup(ajax2['html'], 'html.parser') '

Thank you!

Comment: ur welcome. if solved please mark the answer as correct.